# Close Full Screen window does not go away in MS Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a problem or bug in MS Excel 2003 where the close full screen mini window does not move or go away. No matter what I do, I cannot  move the window or even click any of the options.

I'm struggling to find a solution, would a macro solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into VBE and click on "ThisWorkbook" and the go up to view and select Code.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Application.DisplayFullScreen = True

End Sub

then you will need to turn it off...

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
'Closes workbook without saving changes
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

i have a button (just an inserted shape) on my sheet to exit the program, linked with the macro to close the workbook and exit full screen mode.